# Certain field in django modelform not updating

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using a Django modelform to update data, and for some reason one field is not updating, while all others are.

The model:

```
class Five(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    second = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    third = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fourth = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fifth = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    edited = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The modelForm:

```
class FiveForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Five
        exclude = ['edited']
```

The view:

```
if (request.method == "POST"):
  form = fiveForm.FiveForm(request.POST)
  edited = 1
if (form.is_valid()):
  new_five = form.save(commit=False)
  new_five.edited = edited
  new_five = form.save()
```

The markup:

```
<form action="{% url 'choose' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p id="formname"></p>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Full Name:</td><td>{{ form.name }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email Address:</td><td>{{ form.email }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Your College:</td><td>{{ form.school }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Choice 1:</td><td>{{ form.first }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Choice 2:</td><td>{{ form.second }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Choice 3:</td><td>{{ form.third }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Choice 4:</td><td>{{ form.fourth }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Choice 5:</td><td>{{ form.fifth }}</td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg sub" value="High 5!" />
    </form>
```

For some reason, every field except `name` is updated in the database. Can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you sure it is just name? Looking at the code, `edited` should not be updated either ..

Comment: @petkostas I know that. `new_five = form.save()` would __not__ update the `edited` field. Read the code. It should be `new_five.save()`

Comment: Another thing, just use `{{form.as_table|safe}}`. This would automatically render the form as table for you, rather than you manually creating the `tr` and `td`

Comment: @karthikr not sure what was happening before, but I made your suggested changes and it works now. Thanks much

Comment: @karthikr you shouldn't need to use the `safe` filter -- `{{ form.as_table }}` should work.

Comment: @karthikr correct, sorry just glanced to the code quickly. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the save method of the instance `new_five` after you have modified it.

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_five = form.save(commit=False)
    new_five.edited = edited
    new_five.save()
```

Currently, you are calling the form's save method twice, which won't work.